# How to use queue an event in laravel 5.2?

Tags: events, queue, listener, laravel-5

I am using event to delete particular information.
I have **DeleteCourseConfirmation** event listener and **DeleteBranchCourse** event.

It works fine.

Here is the code for **DeleteBranchCourse** event

```
class DeleteBranchCourse extends Event{
use SerializesModels;

private $fee;
private $feeId;
public function __construct($fee,$feeId)
{
    $this->fee=$fee;
    $this->feeId=$feeId;

}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return [];
}
public function deleteCourse()
{
     $this->fee->destroy($this->feeId);
}}
```

Here is the code for **DeleteCourseConfirmation** event listener

```
class DeleteCourseConfirmation{

public function __construct()
{

}

public function handle(DeleteBranchCourse $event)
{

    $event->deleteCourse();
}}
```

But when i tried **php artisan queue:listen** after implementing **ShouldQueue** interface in **DeleteCourseConfirmation**  to queue event listeners

```
class DeleteCourseConfirmation implements ShouldQueue{
use InteractsWithQueue;
public function __construct()
{

}

public function handle(DeleteBranchCourse $event)
{

    $event->deleteCourse();
}}
```

an error occurs.

> No query results for model [App\Modules\Branch\Models\Fee]

I am following Laravel 5.2 documentation **Queued Event Listeners**

Comment: what about your event fire? Please provide the code

Comment: Event::fire(new DeleteBranchCourse($fee,$feeId));

Comment: Queued data are storing in jobs table but 0 attempts.

Comment: when i run   php artisan queue:listen ,  it makes attempts but getting No query results for model [App\Modules\Branch\Models\Fee] error

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

First i changed the Event fire code

```
Event::fire(new DeleteBranchCourse($fee,$feeId));
```

to 
 `Event::fire(new DeleteBranchCourse($feeId));`

Because i don't need to send Fee model's object to DeleteBranchCourse's constructor.

and i change DeleteBranchCourse class to this

```
class DeleteBranchCourse extends Event{
use SerializesModels;

private $feeId;
public function __construct($feeId)
{
    $this->feeId=$feeId;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return [];
}
public function deleteCourse()
{
     Fee::destroy($this->feeId);
}}
```

And finally running this command from terminal

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

or changing the handle function of listeners class to this

```
public function handle(DeleteBranchCourse $event)
{

    $this->attempts($event->deleteCourse());
}}
```